# building compound query in elasticsearch

Tags: java, elasticsearch, logical-operators, booleanquery

I was trying to search the following case using BoolQueryBuilder in elasticsearch

```
 select * from students where (name = "XXX" and rollno = 1) or (name = "YYY" and rollno = 2)
```

I have to build query builder for it.

Can anyone suggest me the BoolQueryBuilder to build the query.

ElasticSearch 6.1.2

Any help really appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here it is:

```
GET students/_search
{
  "query": {
  "bool": {
     "should": [
        {
           "bool": {
              "must": [
                 {
                    "term": {
                       "name": {
                          "value": "XXX"
                       }
                    }
                 },
                 {
                    "term": {
                       "rollno": {
                          "value": "1"
                       }
                    }
                 }
              ]
           }
        },
        {
           "bool": {
              "must": [
                 {
                    "term": {
                       "name": {
                          "value": "YYY"
                       }
                    }
                 },
                 {
                    "term": {
                       "rollno": {
                          "value": "2"
                       }
                    }
                 }
              ]
           }
        }
     ]
  }}}
```

Basically, bool compound query can apply into deeper level. The rest is about how you use in case of `OR` or `AND` operation. 
In this case, `should` map to `OR`, and `must` map to `AND`.

Cheers,

Answer (score 1):

This is java api to build the BooleanQueryBuilder condition

```
        BoolQueryBuilder booleanQuery = QueryBuilders.boolQuery();
        booleanQuery.must(QueryBuilders.termQuery("name", "XXX"));
        booleanQuery.must(QueryBuilders.termQuery("rollno", 1));

        BoolQueryBuilder booleanQuery2 = QueryBuilders.boolQuery();
        booleanQuery2.must(QueryBuilders.termQuery("name", "YYY"));
        booleanQuery2.must(QueryBuilders.termQuery("rollno", 2));

        BoolQueryBuilder boolQueryBuilder3 = QueryBuilders.boolQuery();
        boolQueryBuilder3.should(booleanQuery2);
        boolQueryBuilder3.should(booleanQuery);
```